# how to build different os compatibility binaries with vs2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am working with visual studio 2008 professional edition. 
I want to run vs2008 compile binaries on win2k3r2 
Could any one please help me to build different os compatible binaries using vs2008 ?

Comment: Why, can't you run them now? VS2008 let's you compile to 32bit / 64bit and should work on any modern Windows OS. Does the server have an Itanium CPU or x86/x64?

Comment: Thanks for reply , Actually I want to run vs2008 complied binaries on win2k3r2 server(it is the only requirement). So what are the changes required in vs2008's setting while building these binaries?

Comment: It should not require any changes assuming all the components are installed on the server.

Comment: i ran binaries on win2k3 server without changing vs2008 setting But it is giving error as "This application is failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect" on win2k3r2 server

Comment: I have fixed application-configuration issue by installing correct vs redistributable package on win2k3r2.

Comment: By "to build different os compatible binaries" do you mean different flavours of Windows or do you want to be able to build for other OSes like *nix?

Answer (score 0):

Binaries ought to be compatible, but you may need to restrict your usage of API functions. To enforce this at compile time,set the appropriate preprocessor definition:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply :) 
But the problem is some (xyz.dll) functions are not present on win2k3r2 server because I have complied binaries on win2k8r2 server. Shall I compile binaries on win2k3r2 server itself ?